# Django Template - Convert a Python list into a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

I am working on a Django / Python website. I have a page where I want to display a table of search results. The list of results is passed in to the template as normal.

I also want to make this list of objects accessible to the JavaScript code.

My first solution was just create another view that returned [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format. But each page load required calling the query twice. So then I tried only downloading the data using the JSON view and printing the table using JavaScript.

But this is also not desirable as now the presentation layer is mixed into the JavaScript code.

Is there a way to create a JavaScript object from the Python list as the page is rendered?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Solution**

I created a custom template filter, see *[custom template tags and filters](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)*.

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

def jsonify(object):
    if isinstance(object, QuerySet):
        return mark_safe(serialize('json', object))
    return mark_safe(simplejson.dumps(object))

register.filter('jsonify', jsonify)
jsonify.is_safe = True
```

The calls to mark_safe are important. Otherwise Django will escape it.

In the template:

```
//Without template filter (you'll need to serialise in the view)
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{{ json_data|safe }}');
alert(data.length);

//Using the template filter    
var data2 = jQuery.parseJSON('{{ record_list|jsonify }}');
alert(data2.length);
```

Note the single quotes around the template tag.

Although my next question would be - is it REALLY safe?

### Update

An updated version working in django 1.8 of the above template tag that also handles being passed a flat values list, ie. values_list('myfield', flat=True):

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet, ValuesListQuerySet
from django.template import Library

import json

register = Library()

@register.filter( is_safe=True )
def jsonify(object):

    if isinstance(object, ValuesListQuerySet):
        return json.dumps(list(object))
    if isinstance(object, QuerySet):
        return serialize('json', object)
    return json.dumps(object)
```

Comment: May be we could put `{{ record_list|jsonify|safe }}` instead of `{{ record_list|jsonify }} + mark_safe(), ...`

Comment: ValuesListQuerySet has been removed in later versions of django >1.9. Values_list is told be an alternative. But can you help in updating this solution itself.

Answer (score 25):

## New in Django 2.1: `json_script`

Django 2.1 introduced a new template tag: [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script). It is almost exactly what you are looking for, it might be even better. It converts a Python value into JSON, wrapped in a `<script>` tag. So this template:

```
{{ value|json_script:"foobar" }}
```

... would produce this:

```
<script id="foobar" type="application/json">{"example": "example"}</script>
```

This is not a normal Javascript `<script>` tag, it doesn't run, it's just JSON. If you want to access the contents in your Javascript, you can do so like this:

```
var value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('foobar').textContent);
```

This tag has been coded so that it is properly escaped, a string with `</script>` in it won't break anything, for instance.

Comment: This seems to not work when the Python object is a QuerySet: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 23):

How about a filter that dumps a Python value to JSON? Here's a sample implementation:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/201/

Since a JSON value also happens to be a valid right-hand side for a Javascript assignment, you can simply put something like...

```
var results = {{results|jsonify}};
```

inside your script.

Comment: Works! You may have to also add a blank __init__.py file in  appname/templatetags/ directory

Answer (score -2):

Look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15592905/1981384) too.

But it isn't highload way. You must:

a) Create JSON files, place to disk or S3. In case is JSON static

b) If JSON is dynamic. Generate JSON on separately url (like API) in your app.

And, load by JS directly in any case. For example:

`$.ajax('/get_json_file.json')`

P.S.: Sorry for my English.