# Django pass Python Object from view to Javascript script in template

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-templates

This is a simple  code created only to show the probem,
obviusly the task that this simple code is trying to do can be done without Javascript, but I need to know how I can do this using Javascript, because
In my real code I need it, and It cant't be done without Javascript 
(basically I create a dinamic 2D array with information from the view)

in view.py

in def play_game function

```
...
players = Player.objects.all()
context = {
    'players' : players
}
return render(request,'play_game.html', context)
```

in model.py

```
  class Player(models.Model):

    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    loose = models.IntegerField( default=0)
    win = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=9)
```

In play_game.html

```
 <script>
var players = "{{players}}";
for (player in players) {
    document.write(player.name);
    document.write("  Win:"+ player.win); 
    document.write("Loose: " + player.loose); 
};
</script>
```

Comment: I am using   python3

Comment: so you want to convert `players` to json in the templates?

Comment: I dont't know what that It means. I want to have the object players in the script and use it like a python objetct. Example:

Comment: I would like to do, var played = player.win + player.loose;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [serialize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) your data (players).

```
from django.core import serializers
...
players = serializers.serialize("json", players)
...
return render(request, 'template.html', {'players': players, ...})
```

and in your template/script

```
<script>
var players = {{ players || safe }};
players.map(function (player) {
    document.write(player.name);
    document.write("  Win:"+ player.win); 
    document.write("Loose: " + player.loose); 
});
</script>
```

see [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592811/returning-json-array-from-a-django-view-to-a-template) and [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757022/how-do-you-serialize-a-model-instance-in-django)

Comment: and How  do I do this ? document.write(player.name); If I do document.write(players); I see: [{"model":"game.game,"fields"{"name":"Bob", "win":3,"loose":2} }]