# How to pass JSON from Django to Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, django

Usually Angular get from HTTP request the JSON from server side (like Django).
But, to accelerate rendering, would like to write down on server side the JSON into a Javascript VAR and let proceed Angular on this javascript variable containing the JSON.

My question are:
   1) How to pass this javascript var to angular $scope variable ?
      (without HTTP).

2) Is writing down the JSON into the HTML a bad/good practice ?
      (given my web app is fairly static).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning JSON array from a Django view to a template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592811/returning-json-array-from-a-django-view-to-a-template)

Comment: This is more of an Angular question.
When I have the Javascript VAR, how to pass it into scope ?

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383725/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angularjs-directive

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple $scope = {{ some_django_tag|safe }}. I can't see why it would be a bad practice if you're 100% sure that the output will be valid JS. I actually do this a bit to instantiate the scope on the page load.